# Orthogonal projection and dual operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Suppose $P_L : H \rightarrow H$ is orthogonal projection of closed subspace L. Then, I would like to prove that $P_L = P_L^{*}$ i.e it is the same as the adjoint.

Suppose $l \in L$, then consider $l - P^{*}_L(l)$. Then we have that
$(l,l - P_L^{*}(l)) = (l,l) - (l,l) = 0$ by main property of the dual.

I am having troubles figuring out why $P_L^*(l) = l$.

Comment: What is $H$? Is a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem refers to $ H $ as a Hilbert space.

By definition of adjoint map $P^{*}_{L}$ is the **only** map the satisfies 
$$\left\langle P_{L}(x),y\right\rangle = \left\langle x, P^{*}_{L}(y)\right\rangle $$
for all $x,y\in H$.

For other hand, given $x,y\in H$, since $L$ is closed subspace we have $H=L \oplus L^{\bot}$, then $x=P_{L}(x)+(x-P_{L}(x))$ and  $y=P_{L}(y)+(y-P_{L}(y))$ where $x-P_{L}(x)\in L^{\bot}$ and $y-P_{L}(y)\in L^{\bot}$, that is
$$\left\langle P_{L}(x),y-P_{L}(y)\right\rangle=0 \quad \mbox{and}\quad \left\langle x-P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle=0. $$

Therefore
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\left\langle P_{L}(x),y\right\rangle &=& \left\langle P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)+(y-P_{L}(y))\right\rangle\\ 
&=& \left\langle P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle +\left\langle P_{L}(x),y-P_{L}(y)\right\rangle\\
&=& \left\langle P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle \\
&=&  \left\langle P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle + \left\langle x-P_{L}(x),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle  \\
&=&  \left\langle P_{L}(x)+(x-P_{L}(x)),P_{L}(y)\right\rangle\\
&=& \left\langle x, P_{L}(y)\right\rangle.
\end{array}$$

By the uniqueness of $P^{*}_{L}$  we have $P_{L}=P^{*}_{L}$.